# Перенос БД с 2008 на 2016 MsSql

Tags: sql-server

Есть сервак с базами на 2008 ms sql. Надо его перенести на 2016й. Но 2016й базу не видит. Решил перекинуть в 2014й.Там все видит но появилась другая проблема. На исходном серваке винт с размером кластера в 512 байт, а на целевом 64кб. Можно это как-то решить?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под «перенести»? Detach - attach или backup - restore? Какие конкретно ошибки возникают?

Comment: backup - restore.ругается что база была создана на диске с размером кластера 512байт

Comment: Да, бывает такое. При бэкапе попробуйте задать опцию `FORMAT`.

Comment: спасибо,помогло,но все равно базу не видит 16й сервер.

Comment: все решил,всем спасибо огромное